# Liquid templates in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, liquid

Im trying to implement Shopify's liquid templates in my project & render them from the database.

What would be the prettiest & most "railsy" way of doing this, while keeping my controllers free from excessive clutter?

```
    render text: template.render('name' => name).html_safe
```

seems a bit ugly to me, not to mention possible inheritance logic.

Comment: It looks like you could read `Crafting Rails 4 Application` chapter 3. page 39. `Retrieving View Templates from Custom Stores`

Comment: @toninoj did that work? Could you use the Shopify's templates on your project?

Comment: IS04's comment helped me.
Ill post the solution when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation and wanted to abstract the logic a bit. I ended up with a controller concern with a `render_liquid` method, that injects some default locals and registers a custom file system to find the templates, etc. It somehow looks like this:

```rb
def render_liquid(name, locals, registers = {})
  registers[:file_system] = CustomFileSystem.new(self)
  template = registers[:file_system].read_template_file(name)
  Liquid::Template.parse(template).render!(locals, registers: registers)
end
```

Eventually my controllers just tell to render a template with specific locals:

```rb
render_liquid "page", {
  page: PageDrop(@page),
  chapter: ChapterDrop(@chapter),
}
```